# Biztalk Orchestration Port Problem

Tags: biztalk

I have a biztalk orchestration which which job is to catch all errors that happen on the sevrer.

I assign this is listen on the message box using a filter on error. this works fine.

My problem is that is i need to set a message type. if i choose xml it works fine but is a receieve port crashes with a CSV files the message is wrong and i cant read from it.

Any one got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are handling any failed message at all with the orchestration then you will need to accept that this can happen.

If the message is already xml when it fails in the pipeline you can always cast it to XmlDocument.

However if the message is a flatfile then there is no orchestration message type you can cast it to.

The best thing to do is rather than process these with an orchestration have a send port subscribe to the failed messages and route them somewhere else for manual fixing/resubmission.

Comment: send port subscribe to the failed messages worked like a charm. thanks